# Untrusted Application Problems

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded a program called I-nex so that I could see my CPU settings in Ubuntu. Whenever I try to open it, I get a message that says something to the effect of "This application is not trusted" I tried going into properties, under the permissions tab and selecting the "allow executing file as program" checkbox, but whenever I try to select it, it gets un-selected immediately. I am the root user, so I don't think that this should be an issue. Any help?

I am running ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add this app using PPA!

Open project PPA page:
https://launchpad.net/~i-nex-development-team/+archive/ubuntu/daily

Copy text: ppa:i-nex-development-team/daily

Open terminal and copy or write:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:i-nex-development-team/daily
Accept to add
sudo apt-get sync
apt-get install i-nex
```

Or do it in GUI way:
http://blog.launchpad.net/ppa/adding-a-ppa-to-ubuntu-the-gui-way